# How to access id from JavaScript code and pass it to other function

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my JavaScript code, i want to access id from this code and pass to the function

```
function register_popup(id,name,msg)
{                
    for(var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++)
    {   
        //already registered. Bring it to front.
        if(id == popups[iii])
        {
            Array.remove(popups, iii);                   
            popups.unshift(id);
            calculate_popups();
            return;
        }
    }               
    var element = '<div class="msg_box" style="right:290px" id="'+ id +'">';
        element = element + '<div class="msg_head">'+ id +'';
        element = element + '<div class="close"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div></div>';
        element = element + '<div class="id"><a href="javascript:getchat(\''+ id +'\');"></a></div>';
        element = element +'<div class="msg_wrap"><div class="msg_body" class="msg-wgt-body" ><ul id="chatlog"></ul>'+ msg+'<div class="msg_push" id="textmesage">dg</div></div><div class="msg_footer" ><textarea id="myTextArea" class="msg_input"  rows="4" onkeypress="PushMessage(event , this);"+"\n">  </textarea></div></div>';

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element;  
    popups.unshift(id);      
    calculate_popups();
}
```

I want to get id from this function add pass it to this function I am new in JavaScript kindly help me to solve this problem.
Here is my function

```
function getchat(id)
{
    alert("function reached to the getchat");
}
```

Comment: It is very simple `function getchat(id)
           {
            alert("This is your id==" +id );

           }`

Comment: it doesnot work

Comment: You know, you have to call the function too, right ? xD

Comment: You have alredy have `id` in `register_popup` function as you passed `id` in the function. Just simply call `getchat(id)` from `register_popup` function!

Comment: getchat(id); i call this inside register_popup like this and here is my function  function getchat(id)
                  { 
                    fbChat.getMessages(id);
                  } but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

To execute function from the html you can use `onclick` rather than `href`

```
function register_popup(id,name,msg)
{                
  for(var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++)
   {   
     //already registered. Bring it to front.
     if(id == popups[iii])
       {
         Array.remove(popups, iii);
         popups.unshift(id);
         calculate_popups();
         return;
        }
   }               
    var element = '<div class="msg_box" style="right:290px" id="'+ id +'">';
        element = element + '<div class="msg_head">'+ id +'';
        element = element + '<div class="close"><a onclick="close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div></div>';
         element = element + '<div class="id"><a onclick="getchat(\''+ id +'\');"></a></div>';
        element = element +'<div class="msg_wrap"><div class="msg_body" class="msg-wgt-body" ><ul id="chatlog"></ul>'+ msg+'<div class="msg_push" id="textmesage">dg</div></div><div class="msg_footer" ><textarea id="myTextArea" class="msg_input"  rows="4" onkeypress="PushMessage(event , this);"+"\n">  </textarea></div></div>';

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element;  
    popups.unshift(id);      
    calculate_popups();
}
```

Comment: i want to call this function from  function                                       
                    getchat(id)
                  { 
                    fbChat.getMessages(id);
                  }    i called it from registerpopup  like this getchat(id); but it is not working.